# Is it possible to convert a string into an int, in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to create a `data table` using kibana for a set of data in an index. I'm having a field in my database which is a `String`, and I have to convert it to an `int` so that I could use it for the `sum` aggregation in `Kibana` metrics.

Is there a way that I can directly convert it through `Kibana` or should I go with the `logstash` and do the conversion first?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706361/convert-strings-to-floats-at-aggregation-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the value is in Elasticsearch as a string, there's no way to change it to an integer.  You'll have to drop your index and re-index the data.

At that point you can add an index template or use a `convert` filter in logstash to convert the string to an integer.

Comment: Aside from mutate->convert, you can also specify the type in grok, e.g. %{NUMBER:myField:int}.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706361/convert-strings-to-floats-at-aggregation-time