# reindex while converting a string value of a specific field (present in old index) into a number field value (in the new index)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, reindex

Could I ask, how could I reindex while converting a 'string' field e.g. "field2": "123.2" (in old index documents) into a float/double number e.g. "field2": 123.2 (intended to be in the new index) ? This post is the closest I could get, but I do not know which function to use for the cast/conversion of a string to a number. I am using ElasticSearch version 2.3.3. Thank you very much for any advice !!!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Elasticsearch templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) to specify the mapping for the new index and specify the field as a double type.

The easiest way to build a template is to use the existing mapping.

```
GET oldindex/_mapping
POST _template/templatename
{
  "template" : "newindex", // this can be a wildcard pattern to match indexes
  "mappings": { // this is copied from the response of the previous call
    "mytype": {
      "properties": {
        "field2": {
          "type": "double" // change the type
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
POST newindex
GET newindex/_mapping
```

Then use the elasticsearch [_reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-reindex.html) to move the data from the old index to the new index and parse the field as a double using an inline scripting (you may need to [enable inline scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-security.html#security-script-source))

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "oldindex"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "newindex"
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.field2 = ctx._source.field2.toDouble()"
  }
}
```

**Edit**: Updated to use _reindex endpoint

Comment: Thank you very much masstroy. My problem is exactly in the point you described as: " transform the json during the scan and scroll". I have found googling that it should be possible with _reindex functionality of elasticsearch creating a new scripted field in the _reindex request query, but the exact syntax or the functions are basically nowhere to be found (to my current experience). Just a note: I am *not* using logstash.

Comment: would something like this [1] work if I found a conversion function for the inline script which would transform thevalue of the field from string->float ? [1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423899/renaming-fields-to-new-index-in-elasticsearch/42425103#42425103

Comment: the post closest to the string-> float conversion which I mentioned in the original question is here (sorry to be unspecific before):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706361/convert-strings-to-floats-at-aggregation-time

Comment: My experience has been on ES 1.X so I'm not familiar enough with the _reindex feature of ES. If you do the scan and scroll manually via a script, you could apply the transform there.

Comment: Can you apply the transform with a painless or groovy script on the _reindex endpoint like: `doc['field2'].toDouble()`

Comment: I was able to get this working

    POST _reindex
    {
      "source": {
        "index": "oldindex"
      },
      "dest": {
        "index": "newindex"
      },
      "script": {
        "inline": "ctx._source.field2 = ctx._source.field2.toDouble()"
      }
    }

Comment: I updated the answer with the full steps. I tested this on ES 2.3. On ES 5.x you may need to specify the scripting language as groovy

Comment: Thank you so much ! Now I just have to ask the administrator of our cluster why did they disable inline scripting in ES ;/ But I am sure this will work and I find the exact syntax extremely helpful ! Thank you again !  I tried to create scripted field in Kibana, but it did not work, because scripted fields there require the input field to be numeric if the output is numeric.

Comment: Scripting is turned off by default as a security precaution https://www.elastic.co/blog/scripting-security . It looks like with Elastic 5.x they created their own language called painless which is sandboxed and is thus secure enough to run inline so is enabled by default. But on 2.x you'll have to use Groovy and enable it. You can also install the script on the server, but either way requires your cluster admin

Answer (score 0):

You could use Logstash to reindex your data and convert the field. Something like the following:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "es.server.url"
    index => "old_index"
    query => "*"
    size => 500
    scroll => "5m"
    docinfo => true
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    convert => { "fieldname" => "long" }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => "es.server.url"
    index => "new_index"
    index_type => "%{[@metadata][_type]}"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I unfortunately I am not using Logstash.